# How do I join 2 lists, where one of the lists contains 2 elements?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

From what I can tell LINQ and lambda expressions are the way to go for my particular problem.  At my office I have a list of IM logs in a 2-dimensional array [X length][2 width] such that I can see who IM'ed who.  But the logs consists of 3-digit User IDs and not actual names.

```
arrIMLog[x][1]
```

So, a log entry might look like this arrIMLog[0][0] = 353 and arrIMLog[0][1] = 563 means that User 353 IM'ed User 563.  Then, I have a list of User IDs for which I would like to find out who they have IM'ed from scouring through the logs.

```
lstSuspects
```

As an example, lstSuspects(1) = 353, lstSuspects(2) = 563, etc.  I want to create a new and simple list, lstSuspectsContacted, such that I can find out which unique UserIDs each person on lstSuspects have contacted (# of times does not matter, yet).   How do I do this?

```
var lstSuspectsContacted = (from x in arrIMLog
                            join y in lstSuspects 
             on arrIMLog[0] or arrIMLog[1] equals lstSuspects // join criteria
             select new { arrIMLog[0] or arrIMLog[1]}).ToList();
```

The difficulty I'm having is that I would want to select either the [0] or [1] element in the array depending if there was a match between lstSuspects and the arrIMLog in the other element [1] or [0].  I do not know how to achieve this.

Comment: I don't think your concern is with lambda expressions. Linq is the only tag you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, AB is viewed the same as BA, the direction of the IM is of no importance to me.  The only thing that matters right now is that A and B have been in contact with one another according to the IM logs.  I am trying to figure out who talked to who and the sender/receiver distinction is not important to me.

Comment: Maybe you can do it in more, but simpler steps using non-linq expressions, like foreach loops and if-checks? Why does it have to be so complicated?

Comment: I know I can definitely do it with loops, but I think this might be a set-based problem that can use LINQ and in far less lines of code.  If SO disagrees with me, then I've learned that too.

Comment: Does it need to be done fully in linq? There are much simpler ways without using 2 dimension arrays

Comment: Well, suit yourself. Normally people are after completing the task in as little time as possible.

Comment: No Jun.  If SO feels that LINQ is not the right approach then tell me that too.  I just thought this might be done in LINQ in less lines of code than with looping

Comment: This isn't really list transformation, which LINQ is good at, but more model transformation, going from list to model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that may seem more verbose but will be more extendable as well as readable

You start by defining your Logs and suspect POCO.

```
    public class Log
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Person initiating the contact
        /// </summary>
        public int From { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Person that was contacted
        /// </summary>
        public int To { get; set; }
    }

    public class SuspectConnection
    {
        public int SuspectId { get; set; }

        public List<int> Contacts { get; set; }
    }
```

You can then easily find the connections using LINQ.

```
    var suspectConnections = new List<SuspectConnection>();

    foreach (var suspect in suspects)
    {
        var connection = new SuspectConnection() { SuspectId = suspect };

        connection.Contacts = logs.Where(x => x.From == suspect || x.To == suspect).Select(x => x.From == suspect ? x.To : x.From).ToList();
        suspectConnections.Add(connection);
    }
```

Comment: I noticed you made a distinction between From and To.  How do I make it so that if either the From or To contains SuspectId we want to add the other element, To or From, to the List called suspectConnections?  Also, what does POCO stand for?

Comment: POCO stands for Plain Old CLR Object, which basically means a plain .NET class (e.g. Log and SuspectConnection classes). You can add the other element if the suspectId appears in To or From by using the C# conditional operator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx. `connection.Contacts = logs.Where(x => x.From == suspect || x.To == suspect).Select(x => x.From == suspect ? x.To : x.From).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick go at using lambda joins. Note I have used two joins one for each contact in a contact pair.
I think this would be the most efficient solution as well.

```
int[][] log = new int[][] {new int[]{1,2},new int[]{2,1},new int[]{1,3},new int[]{2,3},new int[]{3,4},new int[]{4,1}};
List<Suspect> Suspects = new List<Suspect>(){new Suspect(){SuspectId =  1, Name = "Bob"},new Suspect(){SuspectId =  2, Name = "Frank"},new Suspect(){SuspectId =  3, Name = "Jimmy"},new Suspect(){SuspectId =  4, Name = "DrEvil"}};


                //order the contact pairs as  2 --> 1 is the same as 1 --> 2 
 var q = log.Select (x => x.OrderBy (o => o))
                // Put contact record into an object which we have an IComparable for
            .Select (s => new Contact(){A = s.ElementAt(0),B= s.ElementAt(1) })
                //Now eliminate the duplicates
            .Distinct(new ContactComparer()) 
                //get the Name for contact A
            .Join(Suspects, contactKey => contactKey.A, suspectKey => suspectKey.SuspectId,(c,s) => new Contact{A = c.A, AName = s.Name, B = c.B})
                //get the Name for contact B
            .Join(Suspects, contactKey => contactKey.B, suspectKey => suspectKey.SuspectId,(c,s) => new Contact{A = c.A, AName = c.AName, B = c.B, BName = s.Name}) 
            .ToList();



//Classes that were used:

public class Contact
{

    public int A { get; set; }
    public String AName { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public String BName { get; set; }

}

public class Suspect
{
    public int SuspectId { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}



//We will use this in the .Distinct() linq method, to find the (and remove) the duplicates  
public class ContactComparer : IEqualityComparer<Contact>
{        
    public bool Equals(Contact x, Contact y)
    {

        //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether any of the compared objects is null. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        //Check whether the id fields are equal. 
        return x.A == y.A && x.B == y.B;
    }

      public int GetHashCode(Contact contact)
    {
        //Check whether the object is null 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(contact, null)) return 0;

        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null. 
        long contactA = contact.A == null ? 0 : contact.A;
        long contactB = contact.B == null ? 0 : contact.A;      

        //Calculate the hash code for the product. 
        return (int)((contactA + contactB) % int.MaxValue);
    }       

}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you Darcy.  Your answer is just as good as the one I accepted, and I learned new concepts from your example.  That being said, I chose Jun's answer because I felt they were all equally good, but that he answered first in time.  It was a difficult choice for me.  Thank you again for your excellent solution.

Comment: No problem. Just be aware that his solution has a greater computational complexity (i.e., will perform worse with larger amounts of data)

Comment: I think Jun Wei Lee's solution is O:m*n. flindeberg's solution is O:n +  m (O:n) which is the same as mine.

Answer (score 1):

One way of solving it by stepping out of the box, since I would never treat this as a LINQ-problem. What I'm doing is to remodel it as a network structure. And we are only traversing the log once, which really might become an issue if we are looking at a large dataset.

```
void ShowCommunication(int[][] communication, int[] suspects)
  {
      var table = new Dictionary<int, Suspect>();

      // We are going through everyone, though 
      // communication.Where(t => suspects.Contains(t[0]) || suspects.Contains(t[1]))        
      // could speed it up, although that leaves us with an incomplete graph
      foreach (var chat in communication)
      {
          if (!table.ContainsKey(chat[0])) table[chat[0]] = new Suspect(chat[0]);
          if (!table.ContainsKey(chat[1])) table[chat[1]] = new Suspect(chat[1]);

          // Remove the if-statement if you want the communication in order
          if (!table[chat[0]].CoSuspects.Contains(table[chat[1]]))
          {
            table[chat[0]].CoSuspects.Add(table[chat[1]]);
            table[chat[1]].CoSuspects.Add(table[chat[0]]);
          }
      }

      Console.WriteLine("All members");
      foreach (var key in table)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("{0} talked to {1}", key.Key, string.Join(", ", key.Value.CoSuspects.Select(t => t.ID.ToString())));
      }

      Console.WriteLine("\nSuspected members");
      foreach (var key in table.Where(t => suspects.Contains(t.Key)))
      {
          Console.WriteLine("{0} talked to {1}", key.Key, string.Join(", ", key.Value.CoSuspects.Select(t => t.ID.ToString())));
      }
  }
```

My helper methods and classes:

```
  class Suspect
  {
      public Suspect(int id)
      {
          CoSuspects = new HashSet<Suspect>();
          this.ID = id;
      }
      public int ID { get; set; }
      public HashSet<Suspect> CoSuspects { get; set; }
  }

  int[][] GetRandomData()
  {
      var list = new List<int[]>();
      var random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      {
          list.Add(new[] { random.Next(10), random.Next(10) });
      }

      return list.ToArray();
  }

  int[] GetSuspects()
  {
      var random = new Random();

      var list = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      {
          list.Add(random.Next(10));
      }
      return list.ToArray();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  As mentioned earlier it was difficult for me to choose a solution but I chose Jun's because he answered first, and within the constraints of my question.  I knew how to solve this problem without using LINQ/lambda expressions, but seeing your solution is helpful for me (another way to attack it).